# Json flattening in Snowflake - array, data object

Tags: arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Fairly new to this but can someone help me?

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "city": [
    {
      "city_description": {
        "text": {
          "st": "capital"
        }
      },
      "city_land": {
        "st": {
          "st": "Other"
        }
      },
      "city_size": {
        "id": [
          {
            "id": "small"
          },
          {
            "id": "big"
          },
          {
            "id": "moderate"
          }
        ]
      },
      "city_type": {
        "id": [
          {
            "id": "1"
          },
          {
            "id": "2"
          },
          {
            "id": "3"
          }
        ]
      },
      "conception_date": {
        "st": {
          "st": "13051977"
        }
      },
      "mark_row": {
        "id": {
          "id": "1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "city_description": {
        "text": {
          "st": "cottage"
        }
      },
      "city_land": {
        "st": {
          "st": "Other"
        }
      },
      "city_size": {
        "id": [
          {
            "id": "small"
          },
          {
            "id": "big"
          },
          {
            "id": "moderate"
          }
        ]
      },
      "city_type": {
        "id": [
          {
            "id": "1"
          },
          {
            "id": "2"
          },
          {
            "id": "3"
          }
        ]
      },
      "conception_date": {
        "st": {
          "st": "15071999"
        }
      },
      "mark_row": {
        "id": {
          "id": "2"
      }
    }
  }
 ],
 "country": {
    "country_code": {
      "coordinates": {
        "id": "00111022"
      },
      "name_of_country": {
        "st": "Belarus"
      },
      "desc": {
        "st": "Non-eu"
      }
    },
    "country_identifier": {
      "id": {
        "id": "99"
      }
    },
    "country_description": {
      "st": {
        "st": "TBD"
      }
    },
    "country_type": {
      "is": [
        {
          "is": "01"
        },
        {
          "is": "X90"
        }
      ]
    },
    "country_id": {
      "si": {
        "si": "3"
      }
    }
  }
  }
```

This is stored in snowflake as a string.
I am able to select the data (eg. first column) for the first array.

I am able to select the data (eg. first column) for the first array:

```
SELECT
f.VALUE:city_description:text:st AS city_description
FROM tableinsnowflake t,
LATERAL flatten(input => t.PARSED_DATA, path => 'city') f
```

I want to do the same for COUNTRY  but seem somehow stuck. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: You need not necessarily apply flatten / lateral flatten for country as it is not an array like city . You can directly traverse through the nested json to get the expected column
Eg : select PARSED_DATA:country:country_code:name_of_country:st from table

Answer (score 1):

The country could be accessed directly from `parsed_data` column without using `FLATTEN`:

```
SELECT
  f.VALUE:city_description:text:st::TEXT AS city_description,
  t.parsed_data:country:country_code:name_of_country:st::TEXT AS name_of_country
FROM tab t,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => t.PARSED_DATA, path => 'city') f
```